How to determine nominal voltage of a 3-phase motor with only partial specs
I have an old AC motor that powers a jointer machine for woodworking from the late 70s. The plate has incomplete specs for the voltage. In other words, the voltage in the plate seems to have been erased (scratched) on purpose.
Readable specs:

Voltage: unreadable (but it should be 3-phase, 50Hz)
Current: 6.5/9.5 A
HP: 2/3 CV
RPM: 1500/3000 RPM

The other particularity is that it's a Dahlander motor. It has two speeds, selectable by an external physical switch. It's a dual-speed, single-voltage motor.
One theory someone has given me is that being an original 220V 3-phase motor at 50Hz, the stator might have been rewound to adapt to the new (at the time) 380V standard for 3 phase power lines (it's a Spanish machine). So according to this theory, this could potentially now be a 380V 3-phase motor.
Someone tested it for me recently at 220V 3PH, and it appeared to turn on and change speed with the switch. No other measurements were made. We tried only the low voltage and without load.
How can I safely determine if it's a 220V or 380V motor?
Additionally, is there any way I can do tests without a 3-phase mains supply (e.g. with a multimeter)? (Otherwise I have to dismantle the motor and take it somewhere else with 3-phase mains every time).

Search data of similar motors. In your case, try to find similar pole change (2/4 poles) dahlander winding motors. If you don´t find, have a look to motors of 2 CV (1.5 kW) and 1500 rpm (4 poles) and 3 CV (2.2 kW) and 3000 rpm (2 poles).  Regular rated current of IE4 motors 2 CV/4 poles/400 V is about 3 A, and for 3 CV/2 poles/400 V is 4.5 A.
Now compare the rated current at 400 V with the data in your plate 6.5/9.5 A, it looks likely a 230 V rated voltage, as they are much greater.
Here is an example from Siemens M11 catalogue from 2003, see file from here

If few data is available, and you can use a 3x400 V Variac (Variable transformer), feed the motor without load from 0 V, and increase little by little the voltage, monitoring the current. No load current should be lower than 40 % of rated. If you can reach 400 V and the current does not increase exponentially, the windings should be 400 V. In case the motor windings are 230 V rated, with an increment of about +15% or +20% of this limit, the windings will saturate and current will increase very fast.

Excellent answer: explanatory, clear and to the point. That's what I'll do, thanks!

To complement the answer, I've found that an alternative to looking up the amperage data on catalogs, the UL 508A's standard, table 50.1 is another source  (e.g. https://www.slideshare.net/ErikBarnes/sa08302002e-control-panel-design-guide#17, on page 17). This a US standard though, I'm not sure if there is an equivalent table from other international standard bodies.
